# Table creation script DB2 to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Could someone please take a look at the script below and tell me why it errors out? It's coming out of db2 (via Razor SQL) and I have been able to correct all the the other erros but I can't figure this one out. It's going into MYSQL. (latest version)

```
CREATE TABLE APCHECKIN (
    CHKBCH_NO INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ENTERDATETIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    VENDOR_NO INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    INVOICE_NO VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
    CHK_NO INTEGER,
    PAIDAMOUNT DECIMAL(14,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CHKBCH_NO,ENTERDATETIME,VENDOR_NO,INVOICE_NO)
);
```

This is the error I get. I'm assuming it's something to do with the timestamp I'm just overlooking it!

```
Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    VENDOR_NO INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    INVOICE_NO V' at line 3
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an underscore in [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp)

```
CREATE TABLE APCHECKIN (
    CHKBCH_NO INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ENTERDATETIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    VENDOR_NO INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    INVOICE_NO VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
    CHK_NO INTEGER,
    PAIDAMOUNT DECIMAL(14,2) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CHKBCH_NO,ENTERDATETIME,VENDOR_NO,INVOICE_NO)
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92758

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It worked great! I figured it was something stupid like that!